# Can i make a material move from one point to another with shader node?

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders, procedural

I saw it in [here](https://youtu.be/CSc_aH25cUY) . You all probably saw this video before.

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I guess it begins with this kind of node organization: *Texture Coordinate* (*Generated* outp*ut) > *Mapping* > *Gradient Texture* > *ColorRamp* > *Diffuse* >* Material Output. Then play with the *Mapping Location* value to move the colors.

[image]

file here: [image]

Comment: Yah.   It make sense . Can you make it happen?

Comment: 2 sec animation?

Comment: On a place or a cube

Comment: On. A plane or cube

Comment: I've added the file if that's what you want

Comment: I got a downvote....i dont know what will happen

Comment: Is it bad for something?

Comment: I don't know why  ;)

Comment:  i didn't see the file befoee. I will check it out ..

Comment: I know why i got a downvote.. cuz am a noob..i did ask a noob question...and the why is genius didn't like it...i hope..someone give him a hug...before he did something worse

Comment: Bo i think it's because you should show a picture to make it clear what you're talking about

Comment: Ohh..ok..i am sorry...i am new in here...as you can see..i will definitely give a picture in future.