# Animated Texture

Tags: animation, texturing, uv-image-editor

Someone can help me? I'm trying to do a animated texture like in these pictures below, some animated lines and circles walking through all my objects, but I just can do it in a single object per time, would like to do it in all my objects like my objects was only one, but I can't lost my original objects textures and colors

[image]
[image]
[image]

My project here
[image]

Comment: are your color stripes procedural? I've answered a similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177051/can-i-make-a-material-move-from-one-point-to-another-with-shader-node/177075?noredirect=1#comment296801_177075

Comment: Yes, it's like this that you did to this cube, but I'm trying to do it to a object with more than one material, idk how do it to all them at same time but keep my original materials too

Comment: Look at this video, I'm trying to do like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9NmIXwUEjA&t=129s

Comment: it would be easier to make a video with animated colors, then use this in an Image Texture (video mode)